# How to move through an array chronologically?

Tags: arrays, swift, func

I am developing a drag-and-drop game where the user moves a label to the corresponding node.

I currently have this code:

```
func setupDragLabel(){
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))

    if random == 0 {
        let numbersArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
        let index = Int(arc4random_unifrom(UInt32(numbersArray.count)))
        label.text = numbersArray[index]
        label.name = "numbers"
        }
    else{
        let lettersArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lettersArray.count)))
        label.text = lettersArray[index]
        label.name = "letters"
    }
    ((self.addChild(label))
}
```

and then for ending the touch:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if label.name == "numbers"{
        if numbersBin.frame.contains(label.position){
            label.removeFromParent()
            setupDragLabel()
        }
    }
    if label.name == "letters" {
        if lettersBin.frame.contains(label.position){
            label.removeFromParent()
            setupDragLabel)
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, the function goes on forever, randomly choosing from the arrays. However, I want to set it up so that the function `setupDragLabel()` moves through each array, and when it reaches the end of both arrays it will move onto the next screen. How would I change my current code (I know it means removing the arc4random, but not sure how to fix that at the top), and what function would I need to write to get it to move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making `numbersArray` and `lettersArray` variable, and then remove the elements that you've already used from these arrays.

```
var numbersArray = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
var lettersArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

func setupDragLabel(){
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))

    if random == 0, numbersArray.count > 0 {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(numbersArray.count)))
        label.text = numbersArray[index]
        numbersArray.remove(at: index)
        label.name = "numbers"
        self.addChild(label)
    }
    else if lettersArray.count > 0 {
        let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(lettersArray.count)))
        label.text = lettersArray[index]
        label.name = "letters"
        self.addChild(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, but what would I have to write to make it choose a new integer (ex: if it chooses 1 and the lettersArray.count is 0, what do i write for it to randomly choose another integer until it reaches 1)?

Comment: if `lettersArray.count` is 0, then nothing would be executed, because you have this condition `lettersArray.count > 0`

Comment: right, so I need a line that says `if random == 0, numbersArray.count = 0` to make it return to let random = Int... how would I write that?

Comment: Do you mean : If `random == 0` and `numbersArray.count == 0` then you want to choose randomly from `lettersArray`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean!